# Typescript definition issue for npm package for node and browser

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

I am using Webpack and typescript to create a package that can be consumed by node and browser clients.
For my package, say, MyPackage, I am able to generate an "index.js" and "browser.js" files where index.ts/index.js has node environment related code and browser.ts/browser.js has browser related code. I am using package.json's "browser" property for this.

```
"browser":{
 "out/index.js" : "out/browser.js"
}
```

The problem is I am running under typescript environment. So in the node client, I can consume the library just fine. This is because (I think), the index.ts has the necessary type definitions.

```
import {MyNodeCode} from "MyPackage" (this works )
```

But in browser client (angular app), typescript compilation fails as the types I want to import are in browser.ts. So when I do

```
import {MyBrowserCode} from "MyPackage"
```

the angular code fails obviously.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? Is there a way I can have different typefinition for node and browser environment? I have looked around for some time but unable to find a suitable answer unfortunately. I have referred to https://nolanlawson.com/2017/01/09/how-to-write-a-javascript-package-for-both-node-and-the-browser/ but that seems a native js environment example.

Please do let me know if I need to explain this a bit further.

Comment: My workaround is to manually create an `index.d.ts` with the exports from *both* platforms. That way, users get working types regardless of platform. It's not ideal, since browser users now see node stuff they can't actually use, but it seems like the least-bad option for now.